# How to use $setViewValue with input date using Angular 1.4

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using a basic input date:

```
 <form name="form">
    <input type="date" name="startDate" my-directive.........
```

I want to unit test the corresponding `myDirective` by injecting values in input using `$setViewValue`.

Basically I decided to use the `$parsers.push` to expect retrieving the date object (since at the end of the parsers chain):

```
link: function ($scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                ctrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                    alert(viewValue);
      //.....
```

The unit test call is like this:

```
$scope.form.startDate.$setViewValue(new Date(2014,8,14));
```

I get `undefined` in the alert.

If I call like this:

```
$scope.form.startDate.$setViewValue('2014-08-14');
```

I obtain `Thu Jan 01 1970` instead of `Thu Aug 14 2014`.

Has anyone ever experienced it? If yes, how to fix it?

Comment: _ngModelController_ have two ways: from model to view, and from view to model. When value passed from view to model, used _$parsers_, when from model to view - _$formatters_. When you call `$setViewModel` logically - direction to view, so would be called _$formatters_ instead _$parsers_

Comment: It's quite the contrary ;) parser is taking viewmodel value, and has to map to model value. So to simulate viewModel change, we have to set it through $setViewValue. (and not $setViewModel)

Comment: can you add plunkr? :-) so we can check it. Also i see, i confused `setViewModel` with `setViewValue` :-)

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you create a plunkr that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I created this plunkr but it works fine here too...http://plnkr.co/edit/BueAIByuXYozWjMy3fzB?p=preview
I search for the issue of my code.

Comment: The error provides from a date mock (aiming to simulate date of now) I have :
`window.Date = jasmine.createSpy('Date').and.callFake(function (long) {
            return long ? new OriginalDate(long) : new OriginalDate(defaultNow);
        });`
Parsers do not like it ...

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, you should call

```
vm.myForm.startDate.$render();
```

after `$setViewValue`

Answer (score -1):

`$setViewValue('2014-08-14');` sets the value to the `value` attribute of the input element. So trying to set the value to a date object is invalid.

From Angular doc: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

> When used with standard inputs, the view value will always be a string (which is in some cases parsed into another type, such as a Date object for input[date].)

I'm confused as to why you got `Thu Jan 01 1970`! Can you double check if the passed string is a valid date string. Also in JS months are 0 based, so for August you need to use `07` and not `08`.

Comment: I disagree. parsers aim to map viewmodel to js model.